# dynamically create a variable in solidity

Tags: ethereum, inline-assembly, solidity, evm

I'd like to include an internal method in my contract that allows the creation of a new uint256 in storage named by a parameter. Something like:

```js
function createUint (string memory _name) internal {
    /*
     * creates a new uint256 named _name in storage
     */
}
```

My guess is that it would require inline assembly, but I can't figure out how

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about a mapping?

```
mapping(string => uint256) myMap;

function setValue(string memory name, uint256 value) internal {
    myMap[name] = value;
}
```